# Append array data into Struct variable

Tags: swift

I want to merge data of array into my struct variable

Below is the code

I want to add distance array values in rest -> distance

```
distance = ["12.44","45.32","56.1","54.22"]
```

merge this distance array into struct variable distance

```
var rest : [Restaurants] = []
var distance : [String] = []

struct Restaurants {
    var name:String
    var lat:Double
    var long:Double
    var distance:String?
}

let rest1 = Restaurants(name: "English Tea House", lat: 31.461812, long: 74.272524, distance: nil)
let rest2 = Restaurants(name: "Cafe Barbera", lat: 31.474536, long: 74.268103, distance: nil)
let rest3 = Restaurants(name: "Butler's Chocolate", lat: 31.467505, long: 74.251908, distance: nil)
let rest4 = Restaurants(name: "Freddy's Cafe", lat: 31.461312, long: 74.272124, distance: nil)
let rest5 = Restaurants(name: "Arcadian Cafe", lat: 31.464536, long: 74.268603, distance: nil)
let rest6 = Restaurants(name: "Big Moes", lat: 31.467305, long: 74.256908, distance: nil)

rest.append(rest1)
rest.append(rest2)
rest.append(rest3)
rest.append(rest4)
rest.append(rest5)
rest.append(rest6)

for location in rest {
    distance.append(findDistance(from: location.lat, long: location.long))
}

// I want to add distance array values in rest -> distance 
func findDistance(from lat: Double, long: Double) -> Double {
    let source = CLLocation(latitude: 31.461512, longitude: 74.272024)
    let destination = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    let distanceInMeters = source.distance(from: destination)
    return distanceInMeters
}
```

Comment: What you mean by merge? Do you just want to set the distances for each restaurant in the array?

Comment: `distance` should be `[Double]`

Comment: The seems like a bad solution for a different problem. Either you want the source and also the distances to it to be constant and that means the distance could be calculated in `Restaurants` initializer, or, you want to constantly update `source` and recalculate distance every time. And then it doesn't really make sense to store `distance` inside the structure.

Comment: @Sulthan Is totally correct. Which is why I spent almost an hour writing my massive answer, breaking this down bit by bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff going on here, so I'll walk you through the solution.

First of all, `rest` is a poor variable name. When I read it first, I thought this was "the rest", like the remainder of something, and was looking for where the "main" data is. Keystrokes don't cost you $, you can afford to just type out `restaurants`.

Secondly, you create an empty array, and manually append all these restaurants to it. Instead, you can just create an array from an array literal, that contains all the restaurants directly. That omits the need to have separate

To answer your direct question, you could use `zip` to iterate the `rest` and `distance` together, but the issue is that the `rest1`, `rest2`, ... variables, which were doomed to fail. What happens when you copy/paste a bunch of lines, and forget to change one of them, accidentally writing `rest.append(rest6); rest.append(rest6)`, forgetting `rest7`?

Thirdly, your `findDistance(from:long:)` function takes two `Double`s (a latitude and a longitude), and uses them to construct a `CLLocation`. But when you look where this function is used, you already have a `CLLocation`, which you decompose into two `Double`s, only for `findDistance(from:long:)` to immediately reglue them back together into a `CLLocation`. Instead, just make `findDistance` take a `CLLocation` directly.

Fourthly, the `Restaurants` datatype is miss named. It's not a plurality of restaurants. It models a single restaurant. Name it accordingly: `Restaurant`

Applying these improvements (and also fixing a bunch of indenting along the way), we get:

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name: String
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var distance: String?
}

let restaurants = [
    Restaurant(name: "English Tea House", lat: 31.461812, long: 74.272524, distance: nil),
    Restaurant(name: "Cafe Barbera", lat: 31.474536, long: 74.268103, distance: nil),
    Restaurant(name: "Butler's Chocolate", lat: 31.467505, long: 74.251908, distance: nil,
    Restaurant(name: "Freddy's Cafe", lat: 31.461312, long: 74.272124, distance: nil),
    Restaurant(name: "Arcadian Cafe", lat: 31.464536, long: 74.268603, distance: nil),
    Restaurant(name: "Big Moes", lat: 31.467305, long: 74.256908, distance: nil),
]

var distances = [Double]()
for location in restaurants {
    distance.append(findDistance(to: location))
}

func findDistance(to destination: CLLocation) -> Double {
    let source = CLLocation(latitude: 31.461512, longitude: 74.272024)

    let distanceInMeters = source.distance(from: destination)
    return distanceInMeters
}
```

## The direct problem

Here I'll illustrate the process I went through to address the direct question. However, ***don't use any of these.*** All these are shitty designs trying to work around underlying flaws in design. I show them in order to demonstrate what successive refinement looks like.

Now, to address the direct question:

### First attempt: using `zip(_:_:)`

A first solution approach might be to use `zip` to iterate both `restaurants` and `distances` in parallel, and then mutating each `restaurant` from each `distance. Something like this:

```
for (restaurant, distance) in zip(restaurants, distances) {
   restaurant.distance = distance
}
```

However, this won't work. Since `Restaurant` is a value type, the `restaurant` variable in the loop is a copy of that in the array. Setting its distance mutates the copy, but doesn't effect the original in the array.

### Second attempt: manual indexing

We can work around this, albeit in a much less pretty way, by looping over the indices:

```
for i in restaurants.indices {
    restaurants[i] = distances[i]
}
```

### Third attempt: skip the `distances` array.

The second attempt works, but if the only purpose of `distances` is for us to fill it with a bunch of values, only to immediately use them and discard them, why do we both having the array at all?

```
for i in restaurants.indices {
    restaurant.location = findDistance(to: location)
}
```

This is still not great, however. The `Restaurant` data type suffers from two stage initialization, which is a [code smell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334970/109689). First we initialize it with `nil` location, then we set it to a real location. Why bother? Why don't we just set the location directly?

```
let distance = findDistance(to: location)
let restaurants = [
    Restaurant(name: "English Tea House", lat: 31.461812, long: 74.272524, distance: distance),
    Restaurant(name: "Cafe Barbera", lat: 31.474536, long: 74.268103, distance: distance),
    Restaurant(name: "Butler's Chocolate", lat: 31.467505, long: 74.251908, distance: distance),
    Restaurant(name: "Freddy's Cafe", lat: 31.461312, long: 74.272124, distance: distance),
    Restaurant(name: "Arcadian Cafe", lat: 31.464536, long: 74.268603, distance: distance),
    Restaurant(name: "Big Moes", lat: 31.467305, long: 74.256908, distance: nil),
]
```

But this is *still* not good design...

## Fixing the flaws with `findDistance(to:)` and `Restaurant.distance`

What does `findDistance(to:)` even really do? Internally, it gets a distance from some hard-coded, unnamed location `CLLocation(latitude: 31.461512, longitude: 74.272024)`. When I say `someRestaurant.distance`, I would expect a distance to me. If it were a distance from some reference point A, I would expect the API to instead be spelt something like `someResaurant.distanceFromNorthPole`, or something to that effect.

Furthermore, why is it the `Restaurant`'s job to store its distance to something else? What if I want `restaurant.distanceToSouthPole`, `restaurant.distanceToEquator`? The API would get pretty bloated, and a `restaurant` type ends up doing way too much. And what if I `restaurant.distanceToMe`? I can move, how is a pre-computed, stored value going to keep up with me as I move?

The solution is not to store a distance at all. Instead, provide an API that users of this data type can use to calculate distances to any point of their own choosing.

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name: String
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double

    func distance(from other: CLLocation) -> Double {
        let selfLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.lat, longitude: self.long)
        return selfLocation.distance(from: other)
    }
}

let restaurants = [
    Restaurant(name: "English Tea House", lat: 31.461812, long: 74.272524),
    Restaurant(name: "Cafe Barbera", lat: 31.474536, long: 74.268103),
    Restaurant(name: "Butler's Chocolate", lat: 31.467505, long: 74.251908),
    Restaurant(name: "Freddy's Cafe", lat: 31.461312, long: 74.272124),
    Restaurant(name: "Arcadian Cafe", lat: 31.464536, long: 74.268603),
    Restaurant(name: "Big Moes", lat: 31.467305, long: 74.256908),
]

let pointA = CLLocation(latitude: 31.461512, longitude: 74.272024) // Name me!

// and now, whenever you need the distance to pointA:

for restaurant in restaurants {
    let distanceFromA = restaurant.distance(from: pointA)
    // This is for the purpose of a simple example only. Never hard code units like this,
    // Use `Measurement` and `MeasurementFormatter` to create textual representations
    // of measurements in the correct units, language and format for the user's locale.
    print("\(restaurant.name) is \(distanceFromA) meters from \(pointA)")

}
```

And surprise, this is *still* not the best we can make this!

## Don't store doubles for lats and longs

That's what `CLLocation` is for. Notice that almost all uses of `lat` and `long` require first boxing it into a `CLLocation`. So let's just store that directly, rather than separating individual components and passing them around independently. This prevents bugs like `useLocation(lat: self.lat, long: self.long /* oops! */)`.

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name: String
    var location: CLLocation

    func distance(from other: CLLocation) -> Double {
        return self.location.distance(from: other)
    }
}
```

However, if you do this, the initializer now requires a `CLLocation` instead of two separate `lat`/`long` `Double`s. This is better for interacting with location APIs (where `CLLocation` is the "common currency" type for exchanging location info), but it's more cumbersome for hard-coded locations like your restaurants, because all of your initializer calls get bloated with a  bunch of calls to `CLLocation.init(latitude:longitude:)`:

```
let restaurants = [
    Restaurant(name: "English Tea House", CLLocation(latitude: 31.461812, longitude: 74.272524)),
    Restaurant(name: "Cafe Barbera", CLLocation(latitude: 31.474536, longitude: 74.268103)),
    Restaurant(name: "Butler's Chocolate", CLLocation(latitude: 31.467505), longitude: 74.251908)),
    Restaurant(name: "Freddy's Cafe", CLLocation(latitude: 31.461312, longitude: 74.272124)),
    Restaurant(name: "Arcadian Cafe", CLLocation(latitude: 31.464536, longitude: 74.268603)),
    Restaurant(name: "Big Moes", CLLocation(latitude: 31.467305, longitude: 74.256908)),
]
```

To remedy this, we can tuck the `CLLocation.init(latitude:longitude:)` away  into a little initializer for convenience. I do so in an extension of `Restaurant` rather than directly in the initial declaration of `Restaurant`, because doing so preserves the compiler-generated initializer (called the "member-wise initializer"), which would otherwise be replaced:

```
extension Restaurant {
    init(name: String, lat: Double, long: Double) {
        self.init(name: name, location: CLLocation(latitude: lat, long))
    }
}
```

Which allows us to regain the previous nice syntax:

```
let restaurants = [
    Restaurant(name: "English Tea House", lat: 31.461812, long: 74.272524),
    Restaurant(name: "Cafe Barbera", lat: 31.474536, long: 74.268103),
    Restaurant(name: "Butler's Chocolate", lat: 31.467505, long: 74.251908),
    Restaurant(name: "Freddy's Cafe", lat: 31.461312, long: 74.272124),
    Restaurant(name: "Arcadian Cafe", lat: 31.464536, long: 74.268603),
    Restaurant(name: "Big Moes", lat: 31.467305, long: 74.256908),
]
```

## Mutability

Restaurant names and locations are unlikely to change for the lifetime of an instance of your app, so there's no need to keep them mutable. So lets fix that:

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name: String
    var location: CLLocation

    func distance(from other: CLLocation) -> Double {
        return self.location.distance(from: other)
    }
}
```

## And Finally...

We've come to the final stage. A well named `Restaurant` that doesn't suffer from the need for two-stage initialization, that provides up-to-date distance data for any points a user might like, and that isn't vulnerable to copy paste errors thanks to `lat` and `long` being glued together into a `CLLocation`.

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name: String
    var location: CLLocation

    func distance(from other: CLLocation) -> Double {
        return self.location.distance(from: other)
    }
}

extension Restaurant {
    init(name: String, lat: Double, long: Double) {
        self.init(name: name, location: CLLocation(latitude: lat, long))
    }
}

let restaurants = [
    Restaurant(name: "English Tea House", lat: 31.461812, long: 74.272524),
    Restaurant(name: "Cafe Barbera", lat: 31.474536, long: 74.268103),
    Restaurant(name: "Butler's Chocolate", lat: 31.467505, long: 74.251908,
    Restaurant(name: "Freddy's Cafe", lat: 31.461312, long: 74.272124),
    Restaurant(name: "Arcadian Cafe", lat: 31.464536, long: 74.268603),
    Restaurant(name: "Big Moes", lat: 31.467305, long: 74.256908),
]

let pointA = CLLocation(latitude: 31.461512, longitude: 74.272024) // Name me!

// and now, whenever you need the distance to pointA you can do this (for example):

for restaurant in restaurants {
    let distanceFromA = restaurant.distance(from: pointA)
    // This is for the purpose of a simple example only. Never hard code units like this,
    // Use `Measurement` and `MeasurementFormatter` to create textual representations
    // of measurements in the correct units, language and format for the user's locale.
    print("\(restaurant.name) is \(distanceFromA) meters from \(pointA)")

}
```

Comment: I need distance in array with other value like "name, lat, long and distance??"

Comment: I want to arrange array according to nearest distance which I'm trying to append in that Restaurant Struct , So I can populate tableview with nearest Restaurants.

Comment: @BilalNawaz My entire post's point is that you don't need (and shouldn't have) it stored in an array. Just compute it when you need it. So in your tableview delegate's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can get the particular restaurant out of your array with `let restaurant = restaurents[row]`, and then access `restaurant.name`, `restaurant.location.latitude`, `restaurant.location.longitude`, and `restaurant.distance(from: myLocation)`. That way your distance is always up to date, and not some stale distance value stored in an array some time long ago.

Comment: One more question how can I arrange the restaurants so that nearest restaurant will appear first?

Comment: @BilalNawaz Sort them by their distance: `restaurants.sorted { $0.distance(from: myLocation) < $1.distance(from: myLocation) }`

Answer (score 0):

If I assume your question correct, you want to fill in the `distance` property of each of the restaurants in `rest` with your `distance` variable. Also, assuming count of `distance` variable & `rest` variable are equal, you can do something like this,

```
if rest.count == distance.count {
   (0..<rest.count).forEach {
       rest[$0].distance = distance[$0]
   }
}
```

Comment: This silently fails (does nothing) when `rest.count != distance` count, which is dangerous. Better to throw an error indicating that there's a problem. Also, if you're going to iterate over the indices of an array, just do so directly: `rest.indices.forEach { i in ...`. Manually constructing a range of indices for an array with `0..<rest.count` is error-prone (in case you accidentally write `0...rest.count`), and doesn't work for array slices and many other collections.